# Protractor css locator for md-select

Tags: protractor

I'm new to protractor and need to know how can i get the text i.e. Connections in the below code block. I need to click this "Connections". Anyhelp would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
<md-option ng-repeat="worksite in vmSplashController.worksites track by $index" id="option_worksite_TRANSFER" ng-value="worksite" tabindex="0" class="ng-scope" role="option" aria-selected="false" value="[object Object]">
    <div class="md-text ng-binding">
        Connections
    </div>
</md-option>
```

Full code

```
<md-dialog ng-cloak aria-span="" id="splashDialog" class="asui-popup-container splashContainer">
<form name="splash">
    <md-dialog-content class="agentDetails" flex>            
    </md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-content class="agentOptions" flex layout="row">
        <md-input-container class="md-input-has-placeholder" id="nav_worksite" ng-if="vmSplashController.worksites.length >= 1" flex="50" layout="column">
            <label class="select-lable">Worksite</label>
            <md-select md-no-ink name="nav_worksite" required ng-model="vmSplashController.worksites.selected" ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.locationCode'}" aria-label="Select Worksite" md-container-class="md-select-custom nav-worksite-selectbox" ng-change="vmSplashController.onWorksiteChange(vmSplashController.worksites.selected)">
                <md-option ng-repeat="worksite in vmSplashController.worksites track by $index" id="option_worksite_{{worksite.locationCode}}" ng-value="worksite">
                    {{**Here that Div is being created i.e. Connections along with other two options**}}
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-actions layout="row">
        <md-button md-no-ink class="md-primary nobg-btn" ng-click="vmSplashController.onConfirm()" ng-disabled="splash.$invalid">
            CONFIRM
        </md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
</form>
</md-dialog>
```

I treid this

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.option_worksite_TRANSFER > div.md-text', 'Connections')).click();
```

but getting the below error.

```
Message:


     Failed: No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText(".option_worksite_TRANSFER > div.md-text", "Connections")
```

Answer (score 0):

First - I'm a bit confused. In example you are trying to select class `option_worksite_TRANSFER`, but in error message it has an id.

If you are trying to select value from dropdown, try this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39047319/6331748

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right I tried with both with "." and "#" but no luck. However as per the example 

element.all(by.model('result.status')).get(0).sendKeys('Acce‌​pt');

They are using model but I have a div element and inside that i have "connection" text which i want to click and based on the ng-change it will do the rest. This was my first question on stackoverflow I'm sorry if anything went wrong by mistake.

Appreciate if any one can use my example and let me know how can i select connection. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this using xpath:

```
element(by.xpath("//div[text()='Connections']")).click();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. Not selecting the value "Connections" from md-option, however it is not showing any error as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('[id^="option_worksite"] > div.md-text', 'Connections')).click();
```

Adding waits:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var ele = element(by.cssContainingText('[id^="option_worksite"] > div.md-text', 'Connections'));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ele), 5000).then(function(){
    ele.click();            
});
```

Comment: Thanks

Please note now I'm getting this error

Failures:
1) ....Selecting the select options - worksite
  'code'
Message:
    Failed: element not visible
      (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.90)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
'code'

Comment: Use expected conditions to wait for elements visibility as below: var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions; var ele = element(by.cssContainingText('[id^="option_worksite"] > div.md-text', 'Connections')); browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ele), 5000).then(function(){ ele.click(); })

Comment: I tried this but no luck.    Message:
    Failed: Wait timed out after 5024ms
  Stack:
    TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 5024ms ///// I even tried to increase the time as well but it does not work, whatever time i will put it will add some milliseconds in it and gives the same error.